# Dynamically add and remove ssh keys to private gitlab repo

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, packer

I need the VM created by the gitlab-ci.yml (running Ubuntu 14.04) to install packer and then both access and download either my entire private gitlab repo, or just an individual file from that repo.

First I tried creating an ssh key in my script that creates the container and vm, and then remotely adding the .pub to the gitlab repo. However I forgot that the newly created container is discarded upon completion of the build. Meaning new keys are generated every time the container is created.

Is there anyway that I can dynamically add and delete keys to a private GitLab repo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To use SSH keys in a GitLab CI Docker container to access other repositories on the GitLab server:

- Generate an SSH key pair (once).
- Add the public key as a [*deploy key*](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ssh/README.html#deploy-keys) every where that key should be granted access
- Inject the key into the container by doing the following:

  - Add the *private* key as a *secret variable* named `SSH_PRIVATE_KEY`
  - Add the following to the `before_script` in your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file
- Inject the GitLab server SSH host key into the container:

  - Add the host key as a *secret variable* named `GITLAB_HOST_KEY`
  - Add the following to the `before_script` in your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file

```
before_script:
  # Add SSH private key and GitLab server host key
  - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
  - ssh-add <(echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY")
  - mkdir -p /root/.ssh
  - echo "$GITLAB_HOST_KEY" >> /root/.ssh/known_hosts
```

Comment: That is pretty much what I ended up with (only just solved it). Thanks man!

Comment: You're welcome. Remember to always up-vote any answer that proves helpful, and accept the answer that best answers your question.